# AutoHotkey script error

Tags: autohotkey

I need that LButton (when up) to release Insert (down and up) key. But it can't release while LButton is down, cuz in the game that I play, one action cancels the other.
I made a script that almost do that, but when I do that fast, one action begins to cancel the other, like LButton (down) was being pressed at the same time that Insert are.

Actual script:

LButton up::

Send {Ins up}

Return

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you could try:

Add `SetBatchlines -1` to the beginning of your script, to make it run faster.
Use SendInput instead of Send. Because it is faster.
Send and {LButton Up} command right before the {Ins up}.
Wait for the LButton key to be released using KeyWait.

```
SetBatchLines -1
LButton up::
    KeyWait, LButton
    SendInput, {LButton Up}{Ins up}
Return
```

Comment: Didn't worked, LButton and Ins continues to be sent at the same time.

Comment: This worked for me: ~LButton::
Sleep 3
SendInput {Ins}
Return

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Stupid me... `LButton Up` overrides the native function of that key. Removing the `KeyWait, LButton` from my example might also do the job btw.